# How to mount a directory in virtualbox with Salt-Stack?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, salt-stack

Currently trying to provision a VirtualBox with Salt. There is a salt-state to mount directories. However, I don't know what the device should be in the state.

The state currently looks like:

```
directory:
  file.directory:
    - user: ...
    - ...
  mount.mounted:
    - device: <somedevicenamewhichIcantgetright>
    - fstype: auto
```

Whatever I try for `somedevicenamewhichIcantgetright` isn't found, and I've looked in the docs [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto) but I can't find anything about this.

Does anyone know what it should look like? I've tried `username@machine:/path/to/directory` and  `file://path/to/directory` (although that should be on the virtualbox itself; I was taking a shot at the pack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to mount a directory from the host to your vm with Virtualbox? If so, you can do that in your Vagrantfile like this:

`config.vm.synced_folder "saltstack/salt/", "/srv/salt"`